# Group by column Having COUNT (column) >1 in a single column

Tags: sql

1. List item

I am attempting to join two tables filtering out an item_id that has a unique value, and displaying any 
item_id that contains the same value. The SQL statement I am using seems to half work except it returns everything I thought I had this figure out but I guess not.

This statement pulls everything.

```
--join two tables filtering out and item_id that has a unique value and displaying any 
--item_id that contains the same value

SELECT inv_bin.bin, inv_bin.quantity, inv_bin.inv_bin_uid, inv_bin.inv_mast_uid,
       inv_mast.inv_mast_uid,inv_mast.item_desc, inv_mast.item_id
FROM   inv_bin left join inv_mast on inv_bin.inv_mast_uid = inv_mast.inv_mast_uid  
WHERE inv_mast.item_id in ( SELECT item_id from inv_mast
                            GROUP BY item_id HAVING COUNT (item_id) >= 1 ) 
      AND inv_bin.bin not like 'rec'
      AND inv_bin.bin not like 'DEFBIN'
      AND inv_bin.bin not like 'DEFAULTBIN'
ORDER BY inv_mast.item_id;
```

However if i remove the *`'='`* from the *`Group By item_id Having COUNT (item_id) >= 1 )`* then the query returns nothing.  I know i have data in the item_id column that is the same:

```
bin        item_id
07C-C15    002-09-121
Z07-OS     002-09-121
```

Anyway can some one tell me where i am going wrong with this it seem to me that useing > 1 would display every thing in item_id with the same value.

Thanks,
Brett

```
bin         quantity   inv_bin_uid   inv_mast_uid   inv_mast_uid   item_id
07C-C15     0          135           70             70             002-09-121
Z07-OS      10         130277        70             70             002-09-121
04C-B21     0          354           289            289            032-36-26
04C-B04     0          356           291            291            032-38-26
02A-B01     2          101           48             48             5-40050720L  
Z29-SKID00  0          117           48             48             5-40050720L
```

Here is the finished statement that produces the desired reults.

```
/*join two tables filtering out and item_id that has a unique value and displaying any 
item_id that contains the same value */

SELECT inv_bin.bin, inv_bin.quantity, inv_bin.inv_bin_uid, inv_bin.inv_mast_uid,
inv_mast.item_desc, inv_mast.item_id

from inv_bin left join inv_mast on inv_bin.inv_mast_uid = inv_mast.inv_mast_uid  

where inv_bin.inv_mast_uid in ( 
SELECT inv_mast_uid FROM inv_bin  
WHERE inv_bin.bin NOT IN ('REC','DEFBIN','DEFAULTBIN')
GROUP BY inv_mast_uid HAVING COUNT(inv_mast_uid)>1 )

and inv_bin.bin not like 'rec'
and inv_bin.bin not like 'defbin'
and inv_bin.bin not like 'Defaulbin'
/*look up filtering out ids based on not like statements*/

ORDER BY inv_bin.inv_mast_uid;
```

Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: I think some sample data would help.

Comment: are you sure you're going against the right database? that should work ...

Comment: Comment out your `AND inv_bin.bin not like 'rec'
      AND inv_bin.bin not like 'DEFBIN'
      AND inv_bin.bin not like 'DEFAULTBIN'` and see?

Comment: What is the table setup for the inv_mast table? Wondering how many times each item_id can appear in the table.

Comment: Sorry tried to make a table in the original post and failed miserably. Thosse 'and not like' statements don't seem to effect the overall result and function lik ethey should. Each item_id can apear up to 5 or six time depending on the bin code. And yes i am sure i am against the correct database short of adding the database name into the table.column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't an answer, just a question/comment:

Without knowing any more details about your database schema, I'm wondering if you're simply using the wrong table for your group-by clause?

If your "inv_mast" table only contained unique "item_id"s, then you'd never get a count higher than one from that particular table.

Try counting on the IDs on the "inv_bin"-table instead:

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM inv_bin
GROUP BY item_id HAVING COUNT(item_id) > 1
```

Comment: you are absolutly right the thin i need to count looks like inv_mast_uid

Comment: It seems because of the  and inv_bin.bin not like 'rec'
and inv_bin.bin not like 'defbin'
and inv_bin.bin not like 'Defaulbin'

Comment: every thing has at least two bins I will have to approach this differently i think

Comment: I'm still a little unsure what you're trying to achieve with the 'bin' exclusions; if you don't want them to count against the duplicate 'item_id's, then consider moving the exclusion into the group-by clause: `SELECT item_id FROM inv_bin WHERE inv_bin.bin NOT IN (...) GROUP BY item_id HAVING COUNT(inv_mast_uid) > 1`

Comment: I'm not sure i fallow that, would the {NOT IN (...)}  do i put the value i don't wan't to include in there? I guess being the absolute noob it took me two days to figure out how to use {group by haveing count} If you could elaborate a little on useing exclusions in the broup by that would be awesome.

Comment: If you wanted to exclude certain bins from counting against duplicate IDs, you would do so in the `GROUP BY` clause, which is the part of your query that determines if there are any duplicates. I just used the `NOT IN` for brevity, because you were excluding string literals. The full syntax would be `SELECT item_id FROM inv_bin WHERE bin NOT IN ('rec', 'DEFBIN', 'DEFAULTBIN') GROUP BY item_id HAVING COUNT(inv_mast_uid) > 1`, or whatever table/column names you need to use

Comment: so this is what gave the results that were desired